# The hitting of the posts in a rugby match.

Tags: statistics

There is this curious phenomena in Rugby Union that even though it may be statistically improbable that a person kicking for goal would hit the post. It happens reguarly. According to wikipedia the dimensions of the fields are.

> The field of play on a rugby pitch is as near as possible to a maximum
>   of 144 metres (157 yd) long by 70 metres (77 yd) wide.[49] In actual
>   gameplay there should be a maximum of 100 metres (109 yd) between the
>   two try-lines, with anywhere between 10 and 22 metres behind each try
>   line to serve as the in-goal area.[49] There are several lines
>   crossing it, notably the half way line and the "twenty two", which is
>   22 metres (24 yd) from the goal line.[49]
>
> Stricter rules apply to the pitch size for matches between national
>   representative teams. The same maximums apply in this case, but the
>   distance between the two try-lines must also be at least 94 metres
>   (103 yd) and the pitch must be at least 68 metres (74 yd) wide.[50]
>
> Rugby goalposts are H-shaped, and consist of two poles, 5.6 metres
>   (6.1 yd) apart, connected by a horizontal crossbar 3 metres (3.3 yd)
>   above the ground.[51]

So with this in mind how would you try to calculate what the chances are for hitting the post and if you have the chances (and it is low) how would you explain it happening so often?

EDIT:

> A regulation football is 28–30 cm (11.0–12 in) long and 58–62 cm
>   (23–24 in) in circumference at its widest point.

The distance between the kicker and the posts do vary but it will be at least be 22 meters.

Comment: Hard problem! I don't know the game, but in hockey one aims where the goalie isn't. So one is trying to almost hit the post.

Comment: @AndréNicolas No goalie here, just two posts and here you go.

Comment: @OP I see you have read my post. Weigh and pressure are irrelevant. The crucial parameter is the angular distribution of the kicks, which can only be described through statistical data, quite dependent on the kicker.

Comment: Can defenders intercept the ball? If so they might have a tendency to concentrate effort on the fat part.

Comment: @AndréNicolas "Can defenders intercept the ball?" No, everybody just waits for the kicker to do their thing, then the game starts again.

Comment: I assume that teams do not have "goons" to give good players concussions. What kind of a game is that?

Comment: @AndréNicolas They do. Notoriously (even though afterwards, when successful, the goons plead non guilty, it was just bad luck, they did not see this was the guy designated to take the kicks, and the like).

Answer (score 0):

Missing data without which the question is unsolvable are the dimensions of the ball, the distance between the kicker and the posts and, quite crucially, the distribution of the direction of the kick (the diameters of the posts can be neglected). Even assuming that this distribution is centered at the middle of the posts, it is nevertheless highly dependent on the kicker, good kickers being those for which the distribution is the most concentrated (excellent kickers manage to achieve a concentrated distribution even when they kick from varied positions and distances).

The simplest case is a kick from just in front of the poles. Thus, the ball is kicked at $(0,D)$, the poles are at $(W,0)$ and $(-W,0)$, the ball is at $(t\sin(\Theta),D-t\cos(\Theta))$ at time $t$ where $\Theta$ is the angle of the kick. To simplify the computations (and since I do not think we have much information on the "spherical" position of the ball when it crosses the line of the posts), let us assume that the ball is round (gasp!) with radius $R\ll W$, then the ball hits a post, approximately when 
$$|D\tan\Theta\pm W|\lt R.
$$
If the distribution $\Theta$ is symmetric with density $f_\Theta$, this is roughly 
$$
\frac{4RD}{D^2+W^2}\,f_\Theta\left(\arctan\frac{W}D\right).
$$

Comment: Can you maybe explain a bit further what you mean by 'the distribution of the direction of the kick'

Comment: Very interesting!